# Videogular + videogular-quality - how to prefetch all streams in advance

Tags: angularjs, html5-video, videogular

I'm using the latest version of videogular and videogular-quality plugin for changing quality of the video.

At the moment the plugin fetches the new stream upon toggling which creates a bad user experience.

Is there a way to prefetch the sources before the user changes quality and to make a smooth transition?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use
https://github.com/noppolp/videogular-quality

and install plugin with bower 
and inject to angular module

```
 "th.co.softever.videogular.plugins.quality"
```